# Prevent widget inspector from being launched in VSCode for flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

How can I prevent widget inspector from launching each time in Visual Studio code. I have seen about 2 to 3 answere online, but either they are not applicable to the latest VSCode OR they are not clear. Please help

Answer (score 36):

On VS Code you can go to:

settings > Extensions > Dart > DevTools > Dart:Open Dev Tools = never

That's it.

Comment: Since there are a million "settings" in VSCode and multiple ways to get there - try File menu -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Dart -> DevTools -> Open Dev Tools.

Answer (score 16):

I found this on [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14984) thread and it worked for me.

open the `settings.json` file and add `"dart.openDevTools": "never"`

Answer (score 2):

By changing settings.json file worked for me.

initially the value was, "dart.openDevTools": "flutter"

change to "dart.openDevTools": "never".

Location of the settings.json file would be:

C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\Code\User